# Multiple spiders in one project - scrapy runs the first spider (from the .py sorted alphabetically) on "scrapy crawl"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

My project folder structure is like this:

```
my_scrapers/
├── scrapy.cfg
├── website1/
│    ├── __init__.py
│    ├── items.py
│    ├── middlewares.py
│    ├── pipelines.py
│    ├── settings.py
│    └── spiders/
│        ├── __init__.py
│        ├── spider1.py
│        ├── spider2.py
├── website2/
│    ├── __init__.py
│    ├── items.py
│    ├── middlewares.py
│    ├── pipelines.py
│    ├── settings.py
│    └── spiders/
│        ├── __init__.py
│        ├── spider_a.py
│        ├── spider_b.py
```

And the contents of `scrapy.cfg` are:

```
[settings]
default = website1.settings
```

`spider1.py` contents:

```
class Spider1(Spider):
    name = "spider1"
```

... and similarly for `spider2.py`, `spider_a.py` and `spider_b.py`

Problem:

1. When I ran `scrapy crawl spider2` it runs spider1
2. When I ran `scrapy crawl` (without specifying a name) it runs spider1

If I rename `spider1.py` to `spider3.py` it runs spider2 by default as in Problem 1 & 2. It seems the spider found in the first .py (alphabetically) is being run irrespective of the name input

The contents of the `website1/settings.py` are:

```
BOT_NAME = "website1"
LOG_LEVEL='INFO'
SPIDER_MODULES = ["website1.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "website1.spiders"
LOG_FORMATTER = 'website1.pipelines.PoliteLogFormatter'
```

Even running `scrapy list` runs the alphabetically first spider in `website1.spiders`. If I edit in `settings.py`:

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ["website1.spiders.spider2", "website1.spiders.spider1"]
```

It runs spider2 by default for any scrapy command. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put import guards in your spider files.  Scrapy is importing each of your spiders and runing any code that is in the global scope